# bind listbox to selected item

Tags: c#, binding, listbox

WP8, VS2012...I'm using msdn Local Database Sample for foundation.

Here's my current setup that is 75% there...

I have MainPage pivot > listbox AllItems that displays all the current items in the database:

XAML

```
    <ListBox
        SelectionChanged="OpenWinePage_Click"
        x:Name="allItemsListBox" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding AllItems}" 
        Margin="12,2,-20,-2" Width="440"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource WineListBoxItemTemplate}" />
```

[image]

I want to be able to click on one of the items i.e. Mark Ryan and have only that item show up in a Details page:

The behind the code OpenWinePage_Click is:

```
    private void OpenWinePage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        // Capture selected item data
        _selectedItem = (sender as ListBox).SelectedItem;

        if (_selectedItem != null)
        {
            // Send ID of selected contact
            string dest = "/WinePage.xaml?toDoItemId=" + ((ToDoItem)_selectedItem).ToDoItemId;
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(dest, UriKind.Relative));
        }
      }
```

When the WinePage.xaml opens, the xaml to show the selected item is:

```
          <ListBox
                    x:Name="WinePageDetails" 
                    Margin="12, 0, 12, 0" Width="440"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding AllItems}" <!--I DON'T KNOW WHAT TO BIND HERE TO ONLY SHOW SELECTED ITEM-->
                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource WinePageListBoxItemTemplate}" />
```

So I get all of the items in the details page, not just the 1 selected item:

[image]

In my ToDoViewModel.cs I have the following to which I am trying to bind?...

```
    // All items.
    private ObservableCollection<ToDoItem> _allItems;
    public ObservableCollection<ToDoItem> AllItems
    {
        get { return _allItems; }
        set
        {
            _allItems = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("AllItems");
        }
    }

    // To-do items associated with the red category.
    private ObservableCollection<ToDoItem> _redItems;
    public ObservableCollection<ToDoItem> RedItems
    {
        get { return _redItems; }
        set
        {
            _redItems = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("RedItems");
        }
    }...et al pivots
```

Do I need to create another observable collection that points to just one item so I can bind to it?

Is this a binding issue? A database issue? How do I get just one selected item to show up on my details page?

Many Thanks for any help!

R

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a NotifyPropertyChanged property e.g. `Public TodoItem SelectedTodo {...}` which you set when the `OpenWinePage_Click` is called. You can then simply bind that specific property to a control: e.g. `<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedTodo}"/>`

Comment: Very new to this :)

1. so I would use NotifyPropertyChanged even if I'm not updating/editing anything? I'm simply looking to view the item in a 'details' page?

2. The Public TodoItem SelectedTodo {...} would go in the codebehind of the MainPage.xaml? Or would I put it in ToDoViewModel.cs prior to //AllItems (see 4th code example in initial thread)?

Also, what would go inside the {...} of SelectedTodo?

3. Can I not use <Listbox.../> (see 3rd code example in initial thread)? Would it be better to use <TextBlock /> as you show?

Thanks! R

Comment: But you are updating it, when you change the value in the click event. If the details page is a separate class, it is better to put it here and set the value from the main class. Last, you can use whatever control you want, but a Listbox only makes sense if you have a list :). If you only allow one selected item to be viewed in the details page, I would choose a different control e.g. TextBlock.

Comment: 'It is better to put it here'...where is here? :)

Comment: In the class of the details page you are using, where you are using it.

Comment: Steven, I don't need to be yelled at. The question has not been answered to my satisfaction. Yo have been helpful and I marked it as such. I'm sorry, but you're working with a new coder who needs things spelled out a bit more.